# A patient is classed as having type A blood. What is the probability that this is his actual blood type?

Tags: probability

I am trying to do this question:

> The blood type distribution in the UK is:
>
> - type A: 41%
> - type B: 9%
> - type AB: 4%
> - type O: 46%
>     .
>
>   It is estimated that every year,
> - 4% of patients with type O are classed as having type A,
> - 88% of those with type A are correctly classed as having type A
> - 4% with type B are classed as type A, and
> - 10% of those with type AB are classed as type A.
>
> Now a patient is classed as having type A blood. What is the probability that this is his actual blood type (i.e. that he is correctly classed as having type A blood)?

Can someone show what to do here?

**Edit**:  Based on the hint from lulu, the probability of testing as having A is $967/2500$ and the probability that the patient has A and tests as A is $451/1250$. Dividing them $(451/1250)/ (967/2500)$, I get $902/967$. Is that right?

Comment: Why do you write each percentage twice?

Comment: accident not meant to be twice

Comment: To address the problem, hint:  compute the probability that a random patient tests as having blood type $A$.  Compute the probability that a random patient has type $A$ AND tests as type $A$.  Divide.  And please edit out the duplicate percents.

Comment: So the probability of testing as having A is 967/2500 and the probability that the patient has A and tests as A is 451/1250 dividing them (451/1250)/ (967/2500)  I get 902/967 is that right?

Comment: Yes, I agree with those numbers.  Well, I did it as decimals (as the numbers were given to us as "estimated" I don't see the need to be precise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine 10000 people being tested.  41%, 4100, are type A, 900 are type B, 400 are type AB, and 4600 are type O.  Of those that are type A, 88%, 0.88(4100)= 3608, are correctly typed.  Of those with type B, 4%, 0.04(900)= 36, are incorrectly typed as A.  Of those with type AB, 10%, 0.10(400)= 40 are incorrectly typed as A. Of those with type O, 4%, 0.04(4600)= 184, are incorrectly typed as A.

That is, of a total of 3608+ 36+ 40+ 184= 3868 people typed as A, 3608 actually are type A.  That is 3609/3868= 93.3%.